# Windows 7 access denied to executables.. by what?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio

Ever since I started using Windows 7 this problem has been bothering me. From time to time I see similar questions popping up on misc forums, but never did I see an answer.
Here are two scenarios that nearly always reproduce it:

**The explorer way**

1. With explorer, navigate to a directory containing at least one exe file
2. Go one directory up immediately
3. Delete the directory just navigated to
4. Yields *Folder Access Denied* dialog stating *You need permission to perform this action You require permission from Administrators to make changes to this folder*, with the buttons *try Again* and *Cancel*
5. Hitting *Try Again* never works immediately. Waiting a minute or so and then clicking it again does work

Note: If in step 2 and waiting a minute or more before going up one directory, the problem does not occur and the folder can be deleted

**The Visual Studio way**

1. Build a project producing an exe file
2. run the executable then close it
3. Immediately build the project again (by changing a single character in a source file for example)
4. Yields *fatal error LNK1168: cannot open /path/to/the.exe for writing*

Note: If in step 2 and waiting a minute or more before building again, the problem does not occur.

**Some specs**

- Happens both on Windows 7 32 and 64 bit, with VS2008/2010/2011
- Happens on 3 different machines
- I do not have a virus scanner of any kind
- I do have a bunch of services disabled, but nothing that prevents Windows from running normally, UAC is disabled as well
- Happens on any type of disc
- I always use a user account that is in the Administrators group

Obviously both scenarios are very similar and extremely reproducible. So I figured some process must have the file open for some reason, and release it again later. However, using sysinternals

```
handle -a
```

the exe file in question *never* shows up. (that is the correct way to use handle, right?) So while explorer/VS are reporting they cannot access the file, handle.exe says it's not in use anywhere. This leaves me rather clueless, so I'm wondering if someone can come up with a solution: why does this happen, and how to solve it?

**Update** in response to the questions asked:

- I could not reproduce the problem in Safe Mode
- A bunch of shell extensions are installed. From SellExView, here are the non-microsoft ones that are common to all machines: NitroPDF, WinRAR, TortoiseGit, TortoiseSvn, NVidia. I would find the Tortoise ones most suspicious, though for both the 'Status Cache' option is set to 'Status cache only for one folder, no recursive overlays' i.e. there is no TortoiseCache.exe running.
- With the explorer problem, ProcessExplorer does not show the executable. It does show the directory of the executable though, but keeps on showing it even after it was deleted so that seems not really related
- With the VS problem, it does happen with VS even when no explorer window is open on the target directory. And again, ProcessExplorer does not show the executable, nor the directory the executable is in. Note that in this 'mode' with VS, the problem only occurs when running the executable. If not running it, I can build it without problems time after time.
- In 'VS mode' *and* an explorer window open on the executable's directory (tested with a C# exe only), it gets weirder: I cannot build again because VS complains the exe is being used by another process. However, if I delete the exe from the open explorer window, this works, and consequently building succeeds. Again, no references in ProcessExplorer whatsoever. Which seems to match my findings with handle.exe (don't PE and handle use the same API internally anyway?)

**Update 2**
It cannot be just explorer: after killing explorer.exe, the VS problem is still there.

**Update 3**
Using Process Monitor as Asher suggests reveals interesting facts: for the explorer mode, there are 10 calls to IRP_MJ_CREATE upon opening the directory. However only 9 calls to IRP_MJ_CLEANUP. All this calls originate from within shell32.dll, so it is definitely *not* a 3rd party install problem. And it is obviously the one missing IRP_MJ_CLEANUP that causes the problem: exactly 1 minute after opening the directory, the System process itself issues the IRP_MJ_CLEANUP call and the file is released, and an be deleted.

However, I still couldn't figure out why this happens. Is it an explorer bug triggered by some change I made?

**Solution!** Looking through the services I have disabled, I noticed the description for *Application Experience* says, and I quote, *Processes application compatibility cache requests for applications **as they are launched***. Sounds familiar. And indeed, after starting the service I cannot reproduce any of the problems anymore and the output of ProcMon is different and shorter. Funny though, because after stopping the service again, everything is still fine and the output of procmon is still shorter.

I tried this on two machines, with all 3rd party stuff happily running and all is still fine.

I'm not sure if this is a real bug (one could say 'what do you expect with disabling services'), but it's not exactly normal that the problem goes away simply by starting a service and then stopping it again.

---

Bounty goes to anyone who can provide a deeper insight in this, else to @Asher for pointing me to ProcMon which eventually led me in the right direction.

Comment: A few questions. Does the explorer issue occur in safe mode? Do you have any shell extensions installed? With your Visual studio issue, if you run process monitor and filter down to your exe does it show anything accessing the file?

Comment: Weird, both scenarios you suggest work as expected for me (no errors). Like sgmoore suggests, bust out Process Monitor and monitor the folders/files.

Comment: @sgmoore see update

Comment: Are you 100% sure that just because the calls originate from shell32.dll that this rules out 3rd party installs? I don't know enough about what goes on at an extremely low level to be sure whether that is true or not, but it is certainly not an assumption that I would have made.

Comment: @sgmoore 100% no, but 99%, yes. My conclusion is not just based on what I wrote here; I have the symbols for all system dlls so I see full function names in procmon's callstack. All calls made by explorer when opening the directory come from classes with names like CLoadIconTask, names which have written 'Microsoft' all over it. I'm a programmer so I have some knowledge on interpreting callstacks. Everything non-microsoft is still disabled in AutoRuns. On another machine it's not, yet the entire procmon output is the same. All these + intuition make me strongly believe it's MS only.

Comment: When you say you have disabled everything non-Microsoft, does this include device drivers? This has all the symptoms of something that is hooking in a low level (eg device driver, shell extension) that is breaking something. If this was an issue within the operating system you would expect more people to have the problem simply because of the number of machines configured that way. Obviously when you start adding other drivers and programs or even disabling some services, then the number of people with a similar configuration to yours drops which is why it is usually the best place to start.

Comment: @sgmoore no, device drivers are not excluded. However none of the machines I use have the same hardware. I compared two of them and the only non-MS driver they have in common are nVidia display drivers (not even the same version). Seems unlikely these hook into the shell, or that I am the only one with the problem.

Comment: You mentioned you disabled some services. Does this include the  Application Experience or Program Compatibility Assistant? If you google for 'application experience delete files' you find some people with what sounds like similar issues.

Comment: I always try to find this post when relating to usb safely eject device and getting "Windows can't stop your <name-here> device because a program is still using it.". Usually after a hour I realize that I need to search for *procmon* in my favorites, like `("process monitor" OR procmon)`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue you are seeing is related to the thumbs.db that Windows explorer creates.
Try to disable this, reboot and see if the problem reproduces.

To disable thumbs.db open Group Policy editor (gpedit.msc), go to User Configuration -Control Panel > Administrative Templates-Folder Options > Windows Components-Viev tab > Windows Explorer. find the "Turn off the caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files" and enable itDo Not Cache Thumbnails.

If it does't work I would try investigating it using Sysinternals Process Monitor. 
use it to watch who is accessing the folder when you get an access denied.
see if it is actually an access denied or a sharing violation which means someone is holding the file.

Comment: Thumbs.db does not exist in win7.

Comment: yes it does. go to Folder Options and enable "show hidden files, folder and drives"

Comment: **Windows 7 does not create Thumbs.db.**

Comment: @kinokijuf [citation needed]?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/2345/how-can-i-suppress-those-annoying-thumbs-db-files-in-windows-vista-and-windows-7

Comment: Windows 7 uses the local thumbnail cache (`%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_*.db`), unless the resource is remote (like on a network share) at which point it will use a `thumbs.db` stored in the remote location (this can be disabled by GP).

Comment: As covered in [this answer](http://superuser.com/q/11858/23133) in the question Asher linked. ;)

Comment: upvoted: although I do not have a Do Not Cache Thumbnails option, using ProcMon finally got me somewhere, as it provides evidence of the problem, unlike ProcessExplorer or handle: exactly 1 minute after opening the directory or running the exe, there is an IRP_MJ_CLEANUP operation from the System process which seems to release the file: right after that event I can delete the directory again. I'll investiagate this further, if I can make sense from what ProcMon provides.

Comment: The desktop theme also might have influence, I know that Airo has a registry setting `AlwaysHibernateThumbnails` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM`, though I do not know the exact purpose.

Comment: @LouisSomers I already disabled anything I could find related to thumbnails via gpedit.msc but no avail.

Comment: @kinokijuf I just noticed you've been messing with Ahser's answer. I have no idea why you are doing it, but it does not make sense: first you say, in bold, that there is no thumbs.db. Then you edit Asher's answer so the part where he says how to disable thums.db, making it unusable ("Do Not Cache Thumnbnails" is for XP). Please don't do such things.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you do not have any security product installed of any kind ?

The scenarios you describe are compatible with the theory that some product is accessing every executable file that is accessed by you in any possible way, making exclusive access to it impossible. This does not have to be an antivirus, it could be for example be an indexer for fast search or whatever (even a virus).

One can test this theory by booting in Safe mode where no products except for Windows are launched at all.

The best tool for tracing file accesses is [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). Another excellent tool for finding all startup products and turning them off and on again is [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902).

Comment: indexing is of, windows search is off as well. I have no 3rd party security or search tools of any kind; basically your suggestion is disable any 3rd party tools in autoruns, then enable one by one?

Comment: If this is not happening in Safe mode boot, then it is absolutely sure that some installed product is responsible. You could use Autoruns to disable startup items in batches and reboot, until you find it. The advantage of Autoruns is that you can easily re-enable items, as well as save/restore/compare the current situation. But still better create first a system restore point, just in case.

Comment: disabled everything non-microsoft under Logon, Explorer, Internet Explorer and services. Problem still exists. Is there a way to compare what's loaded in normal mode vs in safe mode?

Comment: Basically, everything you see in Autoruns is loaded only in normal mode.

Comment: Well, except for Services, Network etc.

Answer (score 2):

File or directory can be opened from kernel mode, then

```
handle -a
```

won't show it and ProcMon will show IRP requests from/to System process.

There's a part of Windows Kernel which is mapped to all processes and there's another part of Windows Kernel which runs in separate process. The latter is called Windows Executive.

So this caused by file or directory opened from kernel mode in Windows Executive process.

Answer (score 1):

It may be Explorer reading icons and metadata from the exe.

Comment: This is a possible explanation for Explorer, but not for visual studio unless Explorer is displaying this folder at the same time. @stijn: Does this happen in visual studio without Explorer?

Comment: @harrymc see update, does happen without explorer (well, explorer.exe is still running, but is not on the directory of the exe)

Comment: And how does one fix this issue?