# Procedure behind Remove device safely

Tags: usb, safely-remove-hardware

Is was wondering what sequence of steps does the OS take when we trigger the remove device safely option?

Are the steps OS (in)dependent?

Comment: Answered here http://superuser.com/questions/646948/what-is-the-rationale-behind-safely-removing-usb-media-from-windows-pcs/646951#646951

Answer (score 0):

- OS try to close all connection with the device.
- If succeeded then the OS will remove it from the list of available devices so none of the program or the OS will know nothing from that device while you not remove it.
- Not succeeded then some program still hold resources on the device. The OS will not close it with force, just display you a message that the device is still in use.