# Can USB be removed from computer without losing pics posted on eBay auction

Tags: usb

Am running updated Windows 10.  I use a USB to move pictures from scanner to the computer so I can upload them to eBay where they appear on my auctions after I add them when listing the auction on eBay.  Now that they are connected to the auctions, can I remove the USB from the computer without the pictures?  Asked an eBay person but she didn't know.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: This question isn't on topic here at Superuser.  You uploaded the pictures to Ebay.  Ebay does not use your local files after you upload them.

Comment: When you upload a picture, you're uploading a copy.  The original remains on the drive.

Comment: This question reminds me of a joke about uploading back to the Internet files you have downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You **can** remove a USB drive from a computer at any time. If you've made any changes to the contents of the flash drive you should **eject it first**.

For more details on why it's unsafe to unplug before ejecting see [here](https://superuser.com/a/646951/670755).

To eject your drive:

- Open up file explorer
- On the left hand side look for your flash drive
- Right-click the flash drive
- Click "Eject"